# Audit framework for data migration application

Tags: java, frameworks, audit

Application which needs to be developed are migrating data from one database to another where sync will happen every hour. Requirement is to build audit framework which can allow user to view how many rows are transferred from which table at what time, whether there are any failure, rollbacks or issues etc...

For this I was taking a look at `Oracle Fusion Middleware Audit Framework`.

Can you suggest any other `open source out-of-the-box audit support framework` which can help building audit system which supports compliance, monitoring and analystics?

Thanks in advance for the help.